# PL/SQL How to convert a record to an assoc array

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, associative-array

I am trying to fetch data from a table(employee) with cursor and save to asso. array. However, fetching data with cursor to a record is more straight-forward and it is troublesome to convert a record to an assoc array(arr). Code below is what I am trying to fetch data to a assoc array and improvement is needed. Or any approaches other than cursor? Thank you.

```
DECLARE
TYPE AssoArray IS TABLE OF varchar2(30) INDEX BY varchar2(30);
arr AssoArray;
table_rec employee%rowtype;
CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT *  FROM employee;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur into table_rec;
        EXIT WHEN cur%notfound;
        -- how to improve the code in the section below,
        arr('col1') := table_rec.col1;
        arr('col2') := table_rec.col2;
        arr('col3') := table_rec.col3;
                    ...
        arr('col50') := table_rec.col50;
        -- end of section
        -- do sth
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: The individual values are readily available from the record. What would be the possible benefits of an associative array?

Comment: if we want to collect/calculate values from a list of column of records, it would be more convenient to use asso. array like arr(col(i)) where i is index.

Comment: Make your calculations directly on the data in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you explain what do you want to get. But I see in your code **arr AssoArray** will contain only one last fetched row and will be rewrite each cycle. Are you realy need it? My suggestion is you want to get some rows of table as associated array.  If its true, you may create the array as table of rowtype and (for example) indexed it by id(if you ID-s is integer).

```
TYPE AssoArray IS TABLE OF employee%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
```

For example

```
create table tmp_table_01 as select * from all_objects where rownum < 11; 

DECLARE 
    TYPE AssoArray IS TABLE OF tmp_table_01%rowtype INDEX BY varchar2(30); 
    arr AssoArray; 
    table_rec tmp_table_01%rowtype; 
CURSOR cur IS 
    SELECT * FROM all_objects where rownum < 20; 
BEGIN 
    OPEN cur; 
    LOOP 
        FETCH cur into table_rec; 
        EXIT WHEN cur%notfound; 
        -- how to improve the code in the section below, 
        arr(table_rec.object_name) := table_rec; 
        -- end of section 
        dbms_output.put_line(table_rec.object_name ||' '||arr(table_rec.object_name).object_id ); 
        -- do sth 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to make comraisons by table structure you may use Dynamic SQL. NExt code get data from table TMP_TABLE_01 sort it by object_id, compare neighbour rows, and return count of difference row.

```
 DECLARE 
   l_sql varchar2(32767); 
   TYPE t_cols_type IS table of varchar2(30); 
   l_cols t_cols_type ; 
   l_result number; 
 BEGIN 
     SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME 
       BULK COLLECt INTO l_cols 
       FROM user_tab_cols c 
       WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'TMP_TABLE_01'; 
     l_sql := 'WITH s AS (SELECT t.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) AS rn FROM TMP_TABLE_01 t) 
  SELECT count(*)   
    FROM s 
    JOIN s sub_s ON s.rn = sub_s.rn - 1 
  where 1=0 '; 
     FOR i IN 1 .. l_cols.last LOOP 
       l_sql := l_sql || ' OR decode(s.'||l_cols(i)||',sub_s.'||l_cols(i)||',1,0) = 0'; 
     END LOOP; 
     dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);     
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql 
     INTO l_result ; 
     dbms_output.put_line('count of conseuence different rows ' ||l_result); 
 END;
```

Comment: the reason why I want a asso. array is that I want to collect/calculate values from an array of target columns names, i.e., namearray. Then I can retrieve some data by looping namearray's index i as arr(namearray(i)).

Comment: Actually, I want to do consecutive rows comparison by columns. As there are many columns, so making it as asso. array will make my life easier. But it seems to be hard to do conversion...

Comment: If I understand what you mean more suitable is DSQL. I add example to my answer